# php twig get variables passed to render in extension function

Tags: php, symfony, twig, twig-extension

I swear I've googled this and tried to understand the docs, but I'm just not getting it. I'm writing a twig function, what I can't understand is how I can access the variables passed into render from inside the function.

So if I have this registering my extension and calling render:

```
$o = new SomeObject();
$twig->addExtension(new MyExtension());
$twig->render('example.html',array('obj'=>$o))
```

And example.html is just `{{ myfunc('foo') }}`
How can I access the variable 'obj' from inside myfunc in MyExtension:

```
class MyExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
  public function getName()
  {
    return 'myextension';
  }
  public function getFunctions()
  {
    return array(
      new \Twig_SimpleFunction('myfunc', 'MyExtension::myfunc', array('needs_environment' => true))
    );
  }
  public static function myfunc(\Twig_Environment $env, $name)
  {
    //how to I get 'obj' from $twig->render in here?
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you really need to do this?  It is more common to just pass the variables that the function needs when you call it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [`'needs_context' => true`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#context-aware-filters) on the function declaration:

```
new \Twig_SimpleFunction('myfunc', [$this, 'myfunc'], [
    'needs_environment' => true,
    'needs_context' => true,
])
```

You'll then get, as a first (or second if `needs_environment` is also true) argument, an array with data of the current context. This will hold your variables.

```
public function myfunc(\Twig_Environment $env, $context, $name)
{
     var_dump($context);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yoshi, that did it. The examples in the twig docs don't use namespaces, but I am, and I kept getting no function errors when twig tried to eval() the name passed into getFunctions(), that's why it's a static method on the class. If there is a better way, I'm open to it.

Comment: @RobertLabrie I've changed my answer to show how you would use a non-static method. Hope it helps! :)